# Цикл работает неправильно

Tags: javascript

цикл идет по каждому массиву и проверяет есть ли совпадение, если да, то ставит знак '+' но в том что я писал работает некорректно, тут должен ставить '+' ко всех 3,2 и 1, но ставит к 2,3 и 5

в чем проблема моего кода?

```js
let x = [
[1,2,3],
[2,8,4],
[3,4,5]
]
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<x[i].length;j++){
        if(x[i]==x[j]){
        document.write(x[j]+'+')
        }
    }
        document.write('<br>')
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в картинке я выделил совпадение которые должны выделитсья, там от каждого красного элемента 2, а это значит если есть 2 или больше одинаковых цифер то выделяется добавлением +

Comment: ниче не понял честно говоря. Что должно в результате быть?

Comment: Если я правильно понял,  есть ряд и мы проверяем есть ли повтор если да то ставим возле этого числа +

Comment: @MihailKosovan да, именно

Comment: сделав `[7, 3, 2] + '<br>'` - ты из массива получил строку `7,3,2\n`

Comment: исправил но все равно не работает

Comment: такое ощущение, что вы тут по контексту сравнивать хотите значения, но по коду сравниваете индексы  и ловите диагональ.

Comment: а как исправить если это так? просто другого решения вроде нету

Comment: за два захода сию задачу решать надо. первый - считаете количество повторов каждого числа. второй - выводите с проверкой, чего там посчитали.

Comment: обрати внимание, у тебя за элемент отвечает **два** индекса, а в сравнении ты только один используешь, по сути ты просто строки сравниваешь

Comment: @teran, там и так два захода, просто сравнивается не то не с тем. А не, все правильно, сейчас только один проход :)

Comment: значит нужен еще один цикл?

Comment: @Grundy ну 2 минуты назад сранивалось `i == j`, так что уже пол пути к победе ). Заход тут один, обход матрицы двойным циклом.

Comment: @Мнебезсахара, добавь пример результата, который ты хочешь получить, сейчас непонятно что в итоге

Comment: @Grundy он хочет к краным элементам добавить плюсики, потому что каждый из них в матрице встречается 2 и более раз

Comment: @teran, все-таки хотелось бы визуально это увидеть :)

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: тогда да, нужен второй цикл. В первом считаешь совпадения, во втором выводишь и если были совпадения - добавляешь +

Comment: не понял, как в первом цикле считать совпадения и во втором выводить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так (сначала проходимся по массиву первый раз и собираем информаию о количестве каждого элемента, потом уже проходим второй раз, проверяем количество по собранной информаии и выводим с плюсом или без):

```js
const x = [
  [1,2,3],
  [2,8,4],
  [3,4,5],
];

const repetitions = {};

for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++){
        const number = x[i][j];
        repetitions[number] = (repetitions[number] || 0) + 1;
    }
}


for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++){
        const number = x[i][j];
        if(repetitions[number] > 1){
            document.write(number + '+');
        } else {
            document.write(number);
        }
    }
    document.write('<br>')
}
```

Comment: и так сойдет, а можно ли без repetitions и flat,reduce? всмысле только с циклами и if else

Comment: Без repetitions нельзя, ведь нам нужно где-то хранить результаты первого прохода. Но  flat и reduce можно заменить вложенными циклами. Я отредактировал ответ.